# OpenCV for Android: how to copy a Mat object (image) to another Mat?

Tags: android, opencv

Both Mat objects contain (different) images. I want to copy `mSnapshot` over `mRgba`.
I tried these (separately), but none of them seem to change `mRgba`:

```
mSnapshot.assignTo(mRgba);
mSnapshot.copyTo(mRgba);
mRgba = mSnapshot;
```

This throws an exception:

```
mRgba.setTo(mSnapshot);
```

And this does work, and sets `mRgba` to be a completely black image:

```
mRgba.setTo(new Scalar(0,0,0,255));
```

What am I missing?

[Edit]
The source files and exception can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-0tS2dxEWQ-OGI3NWFkOGYtYTczMS00YWIyLThlNjgtM2RkMDI4NzFkNDQ2).

Comment: might be msnapshot is a non-4 channel mat? please post the defenition of both mat objects. are you using c++? java?

Comment: and please post the exception

Comment: `mRgba = new Mat();`

`capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);`

`mSnapshot = new Mat();`

`capture.retrieve(mSnapshot, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);`

Comment: I will add the exception later, can't run it now.

Comment: `mSnapshot.copyTo(mRgba)` should do the job. Please show more code because currently it is unclear why you are not able to make a copy.

Comment: I added a link to the source files and exception.

Answer (score 3):

To copy an image, you should use the `clone()` member function like this:

```
capture.retrieve(mSnapshot, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
mRgba = mSnapshot.clone();
```

Another note, OpenCV stores information in BGR order; therefore, your line:

```
mRgba.setTo(new Scalar(0,0,0,255));
```

**Edited for clarity :** This command is setting each pixel to (0, 0, 0, 255), so channels 1-3 are set to 0, and channel 4 (alpha) is set to 255. What if you tried this:

```
mRgba.setTo(new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 0)); // should be set to green.
```

Also, note that you can only use `setTo` once the matrix is allocated.

Hope that helps!

Comment: `setTo` is not able to work on specific channel. It always modify all channels. So you are wrong about it. And while `clone()` can be used for making a copy, `copyTo` is usually a better choice.

Comment: @AndreyKamaev I know that `setTo` cannot set channels independently, and I don't believe I said as such. That is why the `split` and `merge` functions are used to process separate channels. I will try to remove any ambiguity from answer. Also, you're right `copyTo` and `clone` are semantically the same, but FWIW `clone` is used more often in the OpenCV source.

Comment: Actually, I had incorrectly counted the number usages. `copyTo` is used ~676 times and `clone` is used ~580.

Comment: Both mRgba and mSnapshot are allocated before the assignment, and both contain some image. `clone()` has not effect, like all the other options. I used `setTo(scalar)` just to test that the code gets to that place at all.